# Nested accordion with dynamic form fields has the same contents in all the child accordions

Tags: reactjs, nested, accordion

[image: Accordion with same content]

I wanted to make nested accordion in react. Where user takes a input as stage name. It will add a accordion with a Add class button.

On Click of Add class another accordion with 2 more form elements (topic and topic details should be generated). When I add more class hours the child accordion gets created in next accordion and not the same one.

Expected

```
Stage  <button> Add stage</button>
  stage 1
     class 1 (Add Class)
         Topic
         Topic details
     class 2
         Topic
         Topic details
```

but it's now

```
stage 1
     class 1 (Add Class)
         Topic
         Topic details
Stage 2
     class 2
         Topic
         Topic details
```

Below is the code

```
const [classForm, setClassForm] = useState([]);
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState('');
  const [hoursInput, setHoursInput] = useState([]);
  const [serviceList, setServiceList] = useState([]);
 


  // onChange
  const onStageChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setInputVal(event.target.value);
  };
  //change hours
  const onClassHoursChange = (e) => {

    setHoursInput(e.target.value)
    
  };

  // onClick
  const addStage = () => {

    setServiceList([...serviceList, {stage: inputVal   }])
    setInputVal('');
    return serviceList
  };


  //Add Class

  const onAddClassBtn = (i) => {

    let newForm = [...classForm];
    newForm = [...classForm,{i,topic:'', details:'',hours: hoursInput}]
    setClassForm(newForm)
    
    setHoursInput('');
    
    return classForm
    
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      
        
          
          <section>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Enter Stage Name:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter Stage Name"
                value={inputVal}
                onChange={onStageChangeHandler}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button onClick={addStage}>Add</Button>
          
          </section>
          <div id="service" style={{ marginTop: '25px' }}>
            <Accordion className='mt-5 p-5 accordion'>
              {
                serviceList.map((singleStage, index) => (
                  <Card>
                    <Accordion.Toggle key={index} as={Card.Header} eventKey={index} className="accordion-header">
                      {singleStage.stage}
                    </Accordion.Toggle>
                    
                    <Accordion.Collapse key={index} eventKey={index} className="item">
                      <Card.Body>
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Group>
                              <Form.Label>Enter class hours</Form.Label>
                              <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                value={hoursInput}
                                onChange={onClassHoursChange}
                                placeholder="Enter class hours"
                              />
                          </Form.Group>
                          <Button style={{ margin: '5px' }} onClick={()=>onAddClassBtn(index) }> Add Class</Button>

                          {classForm.map((cls,i) =>(
                            
                            <Accordion.Collapse key={i} eventKey={index} className="item">
                                <Accordion key={i}  eventKey={i}>
                                  <Card class="classhours">
                                      <Accordion.Toggle key={i}  eventKey={i} as={Card.Header} className="accordion-header">
                                        {cls.hours}
                                      </Accordion.Toggle>
                                      <Accordion.Collapse key={i}eventKey={i} className="item">
                                        <Card.Body>
                                          <Form.Group className='mb-5'>
                                            <Form.Label>Enter Topic</Form.Label>
                                            <Form.Control
                                              type="text"
                                              placeholder="Enter Topic Name"
                                              value={cls.topic}
                                            />
                                          </Form.Group>

                                          <Form.Group>
                                            <Form.Label>Enter Topic Details:</Form.Label>
                                            <Form.Control
                                              as="textarea"
                                              rows={3}
                                              value={cls.details}
                                              placeholder="Enter topic details"
                                            />
                                          </Form.Group>
                                        </Card.Body>
                                      </Accordion.Collapse>
                                  </Card>
                                </Accordion>
                            </Accordion.Collapse>
                            
                          ))}
                        </Form>
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                  </Card>
                ))}
            </Accordion>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              Click here to submit form
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I tried to change index values then it gives same content in all the accordions.